# Binding to multiple ObservableCollections inside a Pivot element in a UWP app. (XAML, C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, windows-10, uwp

I am working on a UWP app for Windows 10 Phone and desktop.

I want to create a pivot control, that has dynamic content and binds to multiple ObservableCollections

I pretty much followed this tutorial: http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2011/12/13/Binding-a-dynamic-Pivot-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

The thing is, that i want the pivot pane to display multiple sections of content, each one with a title and a dynamic count of custom media controls. (basically something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIeSB.jpg sorry for paint)
I want to define the design in the xaml page and to bind the elements to the corresponding item of the ViewModel, but I can't make the content of the Pivot to bind correctly

So far i am unable to display the titles of the sections as elements of the

So, I have the MainViewModel as follows:

```cs
    public class PivotSection
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SystemLabel { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<PivotGroup> Result { get; set; }

        public PivotSection()
        {
            Result = new ObservableCollection<PivotGroup>();
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class PivotGroup
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> MediaElementId { get; set; }

        public PivotGroup()
        {
             MediaElementId = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }
    }
```

```cs
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<PivotSection> PivotItems { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        PivotItems = new ObservableCollection<PivotSection>();
        LoadHeaders();
        LoadData();
    }
    //LoadHeaders() implementation
    //LoadData() implementation
 }
```

So, when the MainViewModel class is initialized this happens:
1. PivotItems object is initialized
2. For each pivot section a new Object PivotSection is created (LoadHeaders())
3. Some PivotGroup items are created, each with title and a couple of MediaElementId strings
4. These items are added using the Result property of the PivotItems object.

Now to the xaml part:

The xaml.cs file assigns the DataContext like this:

```cs
 this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
```

And then the pivot control in the .xaml file looks like this:

```xml
    <Pivot x:Name="PivotPlatform" Margin="0,0,8,77" ItemsSource="{Binding PivotItems}" >
        <Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.HeaderTemplate>

        <Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Result}" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MediaElementId}" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                </ListBox>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </Pivot>
```

At the end, the pivot header is correctly displayed, but there is nothing in the item box of the pivot.
I've spent so many hours on this, I cant see where I'm mistaken.

Comment: Here is a Visual Studio 2015 project, where I isolated the control:
https://bitbucket.org/MrGreeny/pivottestapp/src/cee26e4a7c7ccb48ee021e249407202df6b03f5e?at=master

Comment: I tested with your project and the items in ListBox are displayed (To see the the `Title` of `PivotGroup`, you can put the `TextBlock` and `ListBox` in different `Row` of the `Grid` in your inner `DataTemplate` or use a `StackPanel` instead of `Grid`). Here is the [screenshot of your project](http://i.stack.imgur.com/DBZLA.png). So what do you mean "there is nothing in the item box of the pivot."?

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the feedback. I guess after I wrote up the problem and isolated it into a new project, I somehow managed to get the bindings right.